# How to get automatically generated tickValues for d3 axis

Tags: d3.js

I have a axis with automatically generated ticks:

```
var yAxisRight = d3.axisRight(yScale)
var yAxisRightG = g.append("g")
    .call(yAxisRight);

// What to call here
var yAxisRightTickValues = ???
```

Naively I would think calling something like `yAxisRight.tickValues()` would give me the values, but when they are automatically generated this returns `null`.

**How can I get the tickValues that have been automatically made by d3 (version 4)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a *continuous* scale, you can use `scale.ticks()` to get the ticks passed to the axis generator.

In this demo, the `console.log` shows the ticks of each axis:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([20, 280]);

[100, 50, 210, 350].forEach(function(d, i) {
  scale.domain([0, d]);
  d3.axisBottom(scale)(d3.select("svg").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,"
  + (10 + 25 * i) + ")"));
  console.log("the scale " + i + " has these ticks: " + scale.ticks())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```